# Cancel loading after 10 second

Tags: ios, swift

I want to cancel loading data from the internet if it takes more than 10 second, because there is only one text.

```
let date_start = NSDate()

let jsonUrl = "http://example.com"
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let shotsUrl = NSURL(string: jsonUrl)
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(shotsUrl!) {
  (data, response, error) -> Void in
    do {
      let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves ) as! NSDictionary
      // saving data
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        print("getJson: \(-date_start.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
      });

    } catch _ {
      // Error
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Can't figure out how to stop loading, I want something like this

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("check"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func check() 
{
    if -date_start.timeIntervalSinceNow) > 10.0 {
        // stop loading
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why doesn't that work? Start the `timer` right after the dispatch method. Use `timer.invalidate` stop the timer.

Comment: because there is nothing where `//stop loading`

Comment: Oh, the title of the question made it sound like it was related to the timing, of or related to a timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let urlconfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
urlconfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
urlconfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 10
self.session = NSURLSession(configuration: urlconfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
```

According To Doc..

**timeoutIntervalForRequest** - The timeout interval to use when waiting for additional data. The timer associated with this value is reset whenever new data arrives. When the request timer reaches the specified interval without receiving any new data, it triggers a timeout.

**timeoutIntervalForResource** - The maximum amount of time that a resource request should be allowed to take. This value controls how long to wait for an entire resource to transfer before giving up. The resource timer starts when the request is initiated and counts until either the request completes or this timeout interval is reached, whichever comes first.

Comment: now it is working, but how to catch the error, app just crashes?

Comment: catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}